# Const-correctness of function parameters on API changes

Tags: c++, function, c++11, arguments, constants

Suppose I am using a library which implements the function `foo`, and my code could look something like this:

```
void foo(const int &) { }

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    foo(x);
    std::cout << (1/x) << std::endl;
}
```

Everything works fine. But now suppose at one point either `foo` gets modified or overloaded for some reason. Now what we get could be something like this:

```
void foo(int & x) {
    x--;
}
void foo(const int &) {}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    foo(x);
    std::cout << (1/x) << std::endl;
}
```

BAM. Suddenly the program breaks. This is because what we actually wanted to pass in that snippet was a constant reference, but with the API change suddenly the compiler selects the version we don't want and the program breaks unexpectedly.

What we wanted was actually this:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    foo(static_cast<const int &>(x));
    std::cout << (1/x) << std::endl;
}
```

With this fix, the program starts working again. However, I must say I've not seen many of these casts around in code, as everybody seems to simply trust this type of errors not to happen. In addition, this seems needlessly verbose, and if there's more than one parameter  and names start to become longer, function calls get really messy.

Is this a reasonable concern and how should I go about it?

Comment: That's not what `const_cast` is for, its intended to _remove_ the `const` qualification of a type. `static_cast` would work just as well for your example.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ Here it says "This type of casting manipulates the constness of an object, either to be set or to be removed." Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Svalorzen It can be used for that, but it shouldn't. It's not the minimal tool for the task. The minimal tool for the task is `static_cast`.

Comment: I think a brickbat to the API designer is in order if `foo( int &arg )` has noticeably different semantics to `foo( const int &arg )`.  In a sane universe, you shouldn't need both, I'd think.  And in the strange cases where you might need both (say, because of function pointer type restrictions), it seems like the non-const version should be able to forward to the const version directly.

Comment: All casts can _add_ "constness" to a type but only `const_cast` (and C-style casts which internally use `const_cast`) can remove it. It's simply not _limited_ to removing the const-qualifier.

Comment: `template<typename T> auto as_const(T&& t)` that converts its input to a `const` reference is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a function that takes a const reference so that it no longer is a const, you are likely to break things. This means you have to inspect EVERY place where that function is called, and ensure that it is safe. Further having two functions with the same name, one with const and one without const in this sort of scenario is definitely a bad plan.

The correct thing to do is to create a new function, which does the `x--` variant, with a different name from the existing one.

Any API supplier that does something like this should be severely and physically punished, possibly with slightly less violence involved if there is a BIG notice in the documentation saying "We have changed function `foo`, it now decrements `x` unless the parameter is cast to const". It's one of the worst possible binary breaks one can imagine (in terms of "it'll be terribly hard to find out what went wrong").

Comment: Seems weird though that as an API user there's no convenient way to prevent accidental mistakes. Casting parameter to const seems to be a relatively painful yet useful method to avoid that any variable modification ever takes place.

Comment: You could declare `x` const in the first place, if it's important to `main` that it doesn't change. But realistically, if someone does this in their API, their API will fail to be upgraded to the new version. You can upset your users with much less than that. It has taken 4 minor versions of Python to get it back so that Python 3.4 is now backwards compatible with the syntax of 2.7. No they didn't WANT to go backwards, but nobody (well nearly) was using 3.0 to 3.3, because you had to modify a lot of code (in particular, libraries).

Comment: The api writer could change the function as easily as adding an overload.  Or `const_cast` away `const`.  A new api is a new api: if the author is untrustworthy, it is untrustworthy.